# VBA - Add sheets to variable and move to new workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro which can create up to 3 new worksheets, and at the end will move those sheets to a new workbook. Some, all or none of those sheets may be created, and I am struggling to move them all. I have tried adding their names to both a string and an array (with and without quotes to mimic if I manually typed the names of the sheets to move).

This is what I have at the moment, but it is returning Run-Time error '9': Subscript out of range. If I only move one of the sheets this works fine, but as soon as there are multiple sheets it stops working. Please could someone advise?

```
Dim SheetNames As String  

if x is True Then
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "a"
    SheetNames = Worksheet.Name
End if
if y is True Then
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "b"
    If SheetNames = "" Then
        SheetNames = Worksheet.Name
    Else
        SheetNames = sheetNames & Worksheet.Name
    End if
End if
if z is True Then
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "c"
    If SheetNames = "" Then
        SheetNames = Worksheet.Name
    Else
        SheetNames = sheetNames & Worksheet.Name
    End if
End if

Sheets(Array(SheetNames)).Move
```

Comment: you need commas between your sheet names, like: `SheetNames = sheetNames & "," & Worksheet.Name`

Comment: You can simply say If z Then ....

Comment: why not create the worksheets in a new workbook instead of the "runaround"?

Comment: **There are several issues in your code** that would be made clear to you by adding the line `Option Explicit` to the top of [every] module [always].  Among other problems are undeclared and misused variables, `Is True` is incorrect syntax (should be `If x = True Then` or simply  `If x Then`, unknown expression `Worksheet.Name` (used several times), incorrect usage of `Move`.  I'f suggest you Google every term that you do not thoroughly understand, and would also benefit from a VBA tutorial.

Comment: Also, you'll need to use the Split function in order to return an array of sheet names, and then you can use the Copy method of the Sheets object --> `Sheets(Split(SheetNames, ",")).Copy`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass a `string` holding all the sheet names inside the `Array()` call.

What you can do is to create an `array` to hold the name of the worksheets you want to move, and call the `move` method afterwards:

```
Sub example()

Dim x As Boolean, y As Boolean, z As Boolean

Dim SheetNamesArr() As String
Dim ArrSize As Integer

x = True
y = True
z = True

ArrSize = 0
ReDim Preserve SheetNamesArr(ArrSize)

If x Then
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "a"
    ReDim Preserve SheetNamesArr(0 To ArrSize)
    SheetNamesArr(ArrSize) = ActiveSheet.Name
    ArrSize = ArrSize + 1
End If

If y Then
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "b"
    ReDim Preserve SheetNamesArr(0 To ArrSize)
    SheetNamesArr(ArrSize) = ActiveSheet.Name
    ArrSize = ArrSize + 1
End If

If z Then
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "c"
    ReDim Preserve SheetNamesArr(0 To ArrSize)
    SheetNamesArr(ArrSize) = ActiveSheet.Name
    ArrSize = ArrSize + 1
End If

Sheets(SheetNamesArr).Move

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I thought that it should have been done using an array but they aren't my strong suit. This has worked perfectly